# Xamarin UWP: Switch IsVisible property in xaml file make the app crash

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

In Xamerin UWP the app crash when I add a switch with the `IsVisible` property to false in the **xaml** file
 `<Switch IsVisible="False"/>`.

The error is that I keep getting is

```
`System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. element`
```

If I set the `Isvisble` property to false in the `OnAppearing` method in the **cs** file it dose not crash.

xaml file:

```
<Switch x:name="s"/>
```

cs file:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing(){
      base.OnAppearing();
      s.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

I'm just wounding why it crash if you set the Isvisble property to false in the **xaml** file but not in the **cs** file?

Note:

- The target version for this is **Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0;
  Build 17134)**
- I'm on Xamarin.Forms version **(3.6.0.264807)**

Comment: I tested your code but I could not reproduce this issue, You could create  a blank app to test, you could also share your xamrin forms version and uwp target version.

Comment: I just added the info into the question above, but here it is again:  Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134) and Xamarin.Forms version (3.6.0.264807).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you are loading your xaml to application. In normal way it works  and sets property correct, but in your case your control does not exist when xaml properties are set. Actually it is odd. Could you recreate your application from scratch and try again? Or delete bin folder, clean solution, and rebuild it again.

it seems the issue with the latest XF UWP  update could you look this link ?https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/151252/switch-crashing-uwp-app-post-upgrade-to-xf-3-6

there is recommendation to bind property  inside  Appearing event include binding  context or roll back to XF 3.5 version.

Comment: I just delete the bin folder, clean solution, and rebuild it again, but the error stilled showed up. Sadly I'm to far into the project to restart from scratch.

Comment: Also could you provide error when application is crushed ?

Comment: I just added the error to the question, but here it is again:  System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. element

Comment: it is issue with new XF 3.6  - I have adjusted my answer